# Selenium Safari WebDriver Not Working

Tags: java, selenium, safari, webdriver, integration-testing

I can get all of these tests to pass except the one for Safari.  How can I can I make the Safari WebDriver test pass?

The Tests:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;


public class SeleniumSetupTest
{

    @Test
    public void testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithChrome()
    {
        WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        testDriver(chromeDriver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithFireFox()
    {
        WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        testDriver(firefoxDriver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithSafari()
    {
        WebDriver safariDriver = new SafariDriver();
        testDriver(safariDriver);
    }

    private void testDriver(WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
        String pageTitle = webDriver.getTitle();
        assertThat(pageTitle, equalTo("Google"));
        webDriver.quit();
    }

}
```

The output from Maven:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.selenium.SeleniumSetupTest
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/jared/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/jared/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.12/logback-classic-1.0.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 2247
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Sep 10, 2013 10:16:23 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 33337
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.583 sec <<< FAILURE!
testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithSafari(com.example.selenium.SeleniumSetupTest)  Time elapsed: 0.09 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Resources.asByteSource(Ljava/net/URL;)Lcom/google/common/io/ByteSource;
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariExtensions.getExtensionResource(SafariExtensions.java:293)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariExtensions.install(SafariExtensions.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:85)
    at com.example.selenium.SeleniumSetupTest.testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithSafari(SeleniumSetupTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)

Results :

Tests in error: 
  testThatSeleniumIsCorrectlyConfiguredWithSafari(com.example.selenium.SeleniumSetupTest): com.google.common.io.Resources.asByteSource(Ljava/net/URL;)Lcom/google/common/io/ByteSource;

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Is your Safari installation up to date?

Comment: I believe so.  I have version Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Safari driver seems to be using [Google's Guava packages](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). The exception you are seeing is telling you that the Safari driver is expecting a different version of Guava then is found. The method `asByteSource(java.net.URL url)` is not found in the Class [Resources](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Resources.java) (which seems to be reflected in the latest [source code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/io/Resources.java))

You will most likely have an older Guava version on your classpath as well which is throwing the safari driver off as it expects a newer one. Inspect your classpath figure out which versions are loaded and resolve your conflict by removing one of them.